# QEMU DOS VGA seeting to make Quake demo working in 640x480?

Tags: qemu, ms-dos

I tried setup MS-DOS 7.1 machine with QEMU 4.2 on Windows 10 1909, but i have problem to make Quake1 demo 1.06 working in 640x480, because of QEMU VGA settings. In 320x200 its working fine.

I tried: -vga cirrus 640x480 is not available, probably emulated GPU has not enough VRAM. -vga std and -vga vmware // 640x480 is available in game menu, but when i tried to set it, im getting: *Unable to load VESA palette in dos prompt and game crashing.*

I need it for some retro benchmarking.

Is there any solution, or its just QEMU bug?

Comment: I have a DOS 6 Virtual Machine in VMware Workstation and it runs 640 x 480 resolution. So it may be a bug in your product.

Comment: Why aren't you using DOSBox for this?

Comment: Im trying to find alternative and compare QEMU, Vmware and Virtualbox, PCem, Dosbox performance with real Dos cards and modern dos machines and other stuff.
   With Vmware, Virtualbox,PCEM, Dosbox its working fine. 

   If you are interested pleas see: https://docs.zoho.com/sheet/open/a2vv94dbc1770534b4037849606de568c62b9

 I also wanted to learn more about QEMU its one of most ambicious SW projects of all, thanks its instruction translation.. It great that i can emulate Power Mac on x86 without 3D and slowly, but still.

Comment: It would be also nice to know if same problems are on Linux too.